# Jmeter- how to deal with popup?

Tags: jmeter

I recorded using a proxy server and cannot see the pop up got recorded.  My pop is a Confirm popup so I cannot use HTTP Authorization manager.  I have to click on OK on this pop up to get to next page.  What do I use for this kind of pop up?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on OK, Does the page get submitted to server?

JMeter will record all the HTTP requests. Jmeter does not execute javascript as the browser does. So, The popup/alert you got, might have been triggered by a Javascript just for some confirmation which JMeter can not record. If the user action on the pop up had triggered any HTTP request, JMeter would have recorded the HTTP request to go the next page!.